# como puedo generar este elemento en windows forms?

Tags: visual-studio

Se que no es necesario abrir un post para esto pero esque no consegui ver un elemento igual el que intentaba era:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Disculpar pero esque soy muy nuevo y el metro framework me esta dando muchos problemas y intentaba poner algun elemento parecido a ese. hay alguno que pueda ser igual?

Comment: es un spinner.. estan en el cuadro de controles.

Comment: busque por spinner pero no aparece, no tendrá algun otro nombre? disculpa de nuevo!

Comment: y si buscas en google controles para windows form?? ademas tenes todos los controles en la barra de controles.. y si no esta el mismo, esta alguno parecido.. pero no son todos iguales...

Comment: vale esque la cosa es que estaba cambiando el diseño de un formulario que esta en metroframework derepente me desaparecieron algunos controles pienso que sea porque cerre el proyecto sin guardar o algo por el estilo el tema esque no tengo ningun incoveniente en usar dependencias externas con metro framework pero en el diseño estaba limitado en la hora de cambiar la apariencia ya que quería un diseño simple y diferente al que tenia actualmente. tenia varias dudas porque varios controles como estos no los encontraba y pienso que la mejor solucion siga siendo usar metro o wpf(no se mucho de este)